# HTML5 & CSS - 2-Sided Box Shadow

Tags: css, html

In CSS I know you able to do a four sided box-shadow. Just wondering whether you are able to select two sides. (Just the left side and the right side). I know there is a question already on this but it didn't provide any useful information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by a four sided or a two sided box shadow. A box shadow consists of a color, x offset, y offset, blur radius and a spread radius.

So box-shadow:red 2px 2px 0px 0px; would only show a red shadow on 2 sides of the element.

Also you can use multiple box shadows at once by seperating them with a comma like this.

```css
div {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin:100px;
  box-shadow:red 0px 2px 0px, blue 2px 0px 0px, green -2px 0px 0px, yellow 0px -2px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple `box-shadows` to achieve the effect

```css
div{
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
    margin:50px;
    background:orange;
    box-shadow:-50px 0px 5px 0px grey,50px 0px 5px 0px grey;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is it, a shame that there is still a small amount of blur on the top. Was just curious for my next website. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can just add this class to achieve your goal-

```
.shadow-left-right {
  box-shadow: -5px 0 5px -5px #333, 
              5px 0 5px -5px #333;
}
```